# How can I make SmartTarget Region configuration easier?

Tags: smarttarget

My understanding is that SmartTarget regions are, under the surface just another trigger. However, in order to manage regions, rather than updating the trigger-types.xml file (as you do for other triggers), you need to update smarttarget_conf.xml, which, taking into account that you have separate config for staging/live can be in 8 different locations per environment (see [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-9BFB388C-00A9-439E-BADC-DBE5B44695B1))

Is it possible to somehow manage regions more simply that this, for example by using Tridion Keywords?

If not, do I really need to update the Regions in all of these places, or is it only really needed in some?

Comment: Perhaps the new architecture in 'Web 8' has a solution to this, as I've no idea how cloud users will be able to manage the creation of new regions.

Comment: I'm just as impressed by what I've seen in the next "Tridion," but the architecture changes are about working with services in familiar ways and CM-side awareness about CD. SmartTarget changes would need to be in the next SmartTarget and I'd defer to Peter's expertise on that. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is not any easier way to manage them, no. They need to be in the configuration file. For sure, they are needed on the website and the web service -- it's possible that they aren't needed on the deployer, but I'm not certain about that.

For now, the recommendation remains to update the configuration file everywhere. We'll try to improve this in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I think Will's seeing the same things as I have from the functional/analysis part. I like Keywords too (or similar) because it all comes down to lists and options. The claim-trigger-footprint setup is helped by having everything based on the ADF, but there are a few things to configure. There's still an impressive, "wow, that's it?" part in the code and requirements gathering. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its not required to configure the regions in the deployer. In my current setup I only have them configured **only** in the SmartTarget webservice. It seems that this is enough to ensure the regions are selectable in the Targeting GUI when creating promotions, and are sync'd to the trigger-types.xml in Fredhopper.

We have not yet implemented Experience Manager so perhaps we will also need to configure the regions in some other places - I will update this answer when I know more.

Comment: Will's answer is accurate. I can confirm XPM does not require any additional configuration in any of the smarttarget_conf.xml files.